# com.xamarin.forms.platform.android does not exist

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just switched from IntelliJ to Xamarin and, man, am I regretting it. Can anyone help me with this error?

I have a Xamarin.Forms project with .NET standard sharing strategy. I'm receiving the error:

> com.xamarin.forms.platform.android does not exist

followed by about 100 errors:

> ... cannot find symbol.

If I create a new project, the errors still occur.

**Android manifest**

Minimum version is `Android 8.0 (API Level 26 -Oreo)`

Target version is the same.

I have also tried each and both with `Use Compile using SDK version`.

**Android SDK**

Installed platforms are `Android SDK Platform 27` and `Android 8.0 - Oreo`

Installed Tools are `Android SDK 26.1.1` and `27.0.1`.

Build tools are all from `26.0.0` to `27.0.3`.

Emulator `27.1.7`

**NuGet - Solution**

All packages updated.

Xamarin.Forms version `v2.5.0.280555`

**Android Emulator Manager**
Operating System is `Android 8.0 - Oreo(API 26)`

The only advice I can find is on SO ... and it is to check manifest versions. I'm at a loss now and am unable to work on any project, have lost three days trying to solve it ... and am very close to switching back to IntelliJ. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Make sure your target framework matches what api's are installed( Located under framework). Check that the Min Android version and Target Android version are what you have installed using the SDK Manager.

Comment: @UsamaAzam I believe I've done that. Could it be anything else?

Comment: I don't think there is any `com.xamarin.forms.platform.android` namespace in xamarin.android. Could you provide a basic sample for reproduction?